# Right Package for Federated Learning

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, federated-learning

Could Someone list the pros and cons with respect to using federated learning with the following packages:

1. TensorFlow federated
2. PySyft

Are there certain tasks which are specific to either or is one clearly better than the other?

Is there any other module which is better than these? If so could you please link them below.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some reasearch, I found that OpenMined (a company based on FL and Private AI) Are making strides to develop PySyft. Hence I would suggest continuing with PySyft.